Profile NodeJS node from roslaunch
I'm currently facing an issue when trying to profile a NodeJS node launched from a launch file. It's declared like that in the .launch :
<node
    pkg="myPkg"
    type="main.js"
    args="--inspect"
    name="name"
>

I'm trying to use the --inspect arg from the nodejs node command like it's explained here : https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/debugging but I have no feedback if whether something happens or not, when looking for used ports it seems like the port usually used when adding the inspect arg is not used at all.
Is there another way to debug a nodejs node and monitor js heap like it's possible with the --inspect arg via roslaunch ?
